# Is there any way in R which can convert the following text currency format in numeric format?

Tags: r, formatting, currency

How can I convert -
this

7k,10k,25.5k

to this

$7,000 $10,000 $25,500

in R? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I confess this might not be the neatest way, but it's the simplest I can think of.  It uses the `scales` package, though.

This is what I did:

```
library(scales)

kform <- c("7k", "10k", "25.5k")

dol <- dollar(1000*as.numeric(gsub("k", "", kform)))
```

It made a vector the way you wanted:

```
> dol
[1] "$7,000"  "$10,000" "$25,500"
```

EDIT: I deleted the old edit because the other way I mentioned actually doesn't work due to the decimal places in the last number.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work:

```
> v <- c('7k','10k','25.5k')
> v
[1] "7k"    "10k"   "25.5k"
> paste0('$',as.numeric(gsub('k$','',v)) * 1000)
[1] "$7000"  "$10000" "$25500"
>
```

Comment: if you have a continuous string `text = "7k,10k,25.5k"` you need this conversion first -> `v = unlist(strsplit(text, ","))`

Comment: this is working fine but in the dataset the same logic is not applicable. It is showing all the NAs as a result. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The other responses work, but `scales` provides nice number formatting for current amounts

```
y <- gsub( "[.]", "", "7k")
scales::dollar(  as.numeric( gsub( "k", "000", y) ) )
```

Comment: your solution seems not to work in the case of `scales::dollar(  as.numeric( gsub( "k", "000", "25.5k") ) )`

Comment: If I use this on the dataset, all I am getting is NAs. Thanks for the help though